# последовательность выполнения кода

Tags: c#

Есть такой код

```
    class TimesOfDay: IEnumerable
    {
        private string[] times= { "day", "night" };
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return times.GetEnumerator(); //System.ArrayEnumerator
        }

    }
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TimesOfDay myTimes = new TimesOfDay();
            foreach (string str in myTimes)
                Console.WriteLine(str); 
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

такой вопрос:. . . подсмотрел что **time.GetEnumerator = {System.ArrayEnumerator}** . . . но в **System** нет такого класса **ArrayEnumerator** . . . а где его найти ?

Comment: `foreach` - это синтаксический сахар. Вы пишете `foreach`, а компилятор после этого рпазворачивает этот код в другой код, где вызывает уже всё, что надо вызывать.

Comment: спасибо вам большое